# No indexar algunas páginas para crear sitemap

Tags: php

Buenas,

Quería configurar el fichero robots.txt para que no me indexe ciertas páginas. En concreto la URL es del estilo single.php?ID="X", donde X es el número del ID, con lo cual la URL no es fija...no sé cómo podría hacer esto:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot 
Disallow: /single.php?ID=X
```

He probado con el siguiente código pero no funciona:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /single.php
```

Comment: estamos hablando de wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

El robots.txt permite el uso de urls parciales y wildcard de modo que

```
Disallow: single.php?id=*
```

Funcionaría. **Peeero**, suponiendo que hablamos de wordpress, y que estás usando permalinks, Google te va a indexar por el permalink, no por el script subyacente, luego no funcionaría.

Lo que sí funcionaría, sería añadir al header de tu theme un condicional que diga: "si estamos en la vista de un post en particular, entonces agrego el metatag robots con valor noindex":

```
if(is_single()) {
  echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">';
}
```

A falta de más información, no puedo darte detalles más específicos sobre donde poner eso, porque cada theme tiene su propia estructura.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No uso Wordpress, HTML puro, con lo cual entiendo que no habría problema. Imagino que si quiero deshabitar más de una URL puedo repetir el comando `Disallow` tantas veces quiera o hay que publicarlo en la misma línea pero con comas?